# Update cURL in a server with Debian 7.8 Wheezy

Tags: linux, curl, debian

I have a server with Debian 7.8 Wheezy and I need the --tlsv1.2 option in curl, which comes in version 7.34 or greater. The problem is that:

```
curl --version
>> curl 7.26.0
```

And 7.26.0 seems to be the latest version in Wheezy.

Comment: Install it from `testing`, it has version 7.38. Read there how to install a single package from `testing` http://serverfault.com/questions/22414/how-can-i-run-debian-stable-but-install-some-packages-from-testing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As commented by [svlasov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1005230/svlasov%20svlasov), here is the answer: https://serverfault.com/a/22418

Comment: Installing across distribution releases like this is, at best, a Very Bad Idea, and Extremely Dangerous. Do not do this unless you have no other choice, and fully understand the potential system-damaging consequences.